# Iterating two list in parallel with thymeleaf

Tags: spring, loops, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my current spring-boot project, I have this thymeleaf code:

```
<th:block th:each="item : ${menu}">
...
              <a th:href="@{/__${menu2}__/listagem}">
                  <i class="icon-asterisk"></i>
                  <span th:utext="${item}"></span>
              </a>
...
<th:block>
```

where I am trying iterate the two lists (`menu`and `menu2`) in a single loop `th:each`. For `menu2` I try this:

```
${menu2[itemStat.index]}
```

but I am getting the error:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1012E:(pos 5): Cannot index into a null value
```

What is the right way to access this second list inside the loop?

**UPDATE**

- controller:

  ```
  @ModelAttribute("menu")
  public List<String> menu() throws Exception {
      return ApplicationClasses.lista_classes_projeto();
  }
  @ModelAttribute("menu2")
  public List<Class<?>> menu2() throws Exception {
      return ApplicationClasses.lista_classes_projeto_2();
  }
  ```
- ApplicationClasses:

  ```
  public static List<String> lista_classes_projeto() throws ClassNotFoundException {
  Locale currentLocale = Locale.getDefault();
      ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", currentLocale);

  List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

  ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
  scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Form.class));
  for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents("com.spring.loja.model")) {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(bd.getBeanClassName());
    lista.add(messages.getString(clazz.getSimpleName()));
  }

  return lista;
  }

  public static List<Class<?>> lista_classes_projeto_2() throws ClassNotFoundException {
  List<Class<?>> lista = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();

  ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
  scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Form.class));
  for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents("com.spring.loja.model")) {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(bd.getBeanClassName());
    lista.add(clazz);
  }

  return lista;
  }
  ```

Comment: Show us the full code for this section as you have gaps currently and we have to make assumptions based on them, e.g. where is the itemStat being populated? Also does the list contain Objects or non-objects for data?

Comment: @Aeseir the section not have any other relevant code which would change the understanding od the code. I add to the question the Java code in controller for the source of the data the thymeleaf code iterate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not having more details i'm making big assumptions when providing this answer.

```
<block th:each="item,itemStat : ${menu}">
<span th:text="*{menu2[__${itemStat .index}__].something}"></span>  // assuming its a object that has parameter called somethin
</block>
```

Your menu 2 list i believe is empty hence the null too.

Comment: Yes, I confirm the menu2 is null in the view (I can't figure out why). Added the Java code from controller with the source of the data (for menu and menu2 - menu is ok, but menu2 don't, despite being almost the same).

Comment: Ok, I re-check the code and finally note I was setting the attribute `model2` in the wrong controller. after fix that, the code works with `${menu2[itemStat.index]}`